# Erro de devolução de quantidade de produtos na exclusão do registro de uma venda em código PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo problemas com meu código que **exclui um registro de uma venda e que deve fazer a reposição da quantidade de produtos na tabela de origem**.

Exemplo de como funciona esse código:

- Na tabela `produto` possui uma **quantidade de 17** produtos do mesmo registro em estoque.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Foi vendido uma **quantidade de 3 produtos** na tabela `itens_venda`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Ao excluir o registro da tabela `itens_venda` com a quantidade de 3 produtos vendidos esses 3 produtos retornem para o registro com 17 produtos da tabela `produto` ficando com uma **quantidade de 20 produtos**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O único problema do código é que **não devolve a quantidade vendida quando o registro da venda é excluído!**.

- Código do formulário de exclusão

```
form method="POST">
    <p> ID item venda:
        <select name="cd_itens_venda" required="">
            <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_selecao as $valor) {
                        echo "<option value='{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}'>{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <button name="Deletar">Deletar item de venda</button>
</form>
```

- Código PHP completo

```
<?php
    require_once 'conexao.php';  
    if(isset($_POST['Deletar'])){
        // Especifica a variável
        $cd_itens_venda = $_POST['cd_itens_venda'];
        try {
            // TABELA ITENS_VENDA
            $conexao->beginTransaction();
            $remove = "DELETE FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            $remocao = $conexao->prepare($remove);
            $remocao->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
            $remocao->execute();

            // TABELA PRODUTO
            // Seleciona o registro do produto a ser excluído
            $seleciona_produto = "SELECT cd_produto FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            // Pega a quantidade de determinado registro de venda tabela itens_venda
            $quantidade_vendida = "SELECT quantidade FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            // Query que faz a atualização da quantidade de estoque da tabela produto
            $atualiza_quantidade = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade + '$quantidade_vendida' WHERE cd_produto = '$seleciona_produto'";
            $quantidade_produto = $conexao->prepare($atualiza_quantidade);
            $quantidade_produto->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
            $quantidade_produto->execute(); 
            $conexao->commit();
        } catch (PDOException $falha_remocao) {
            echo "A remoção não foi feita".$falha_remocao->getMessage();
        }
    }
    // Query que seleciona o registro de itens_venda
    $seleciona_nomes = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_itens_venda FROM itens_venda");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_selecao = $seleciona_nomes->fetchAll();      
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adotar a seguinte abordagem, no teu form você ta recebendo apenas o item do produto a ser removido, o cd_produto não está sendo utilizado.

Quando você recebe ele no PHP no post do formulário, você pode pegar o produto que está sendo removido, ou seja, você vai saber qual é a quantidade dele.

E depois remover o produto, dessa forma, tu já vai saber a quantidade que aquele item venda tem, sem precisar o usar o  `$cd_produto = $_POST['cd_produto'];`

Existem outras abordagens de melhorar o form no frontend e tratar o envio dele via javascript já mandando a quantidade que está sendo removida daquele item.

Comment: Eu entendi que não estou usando o ```$cd_produto = $_POST['cd_produto']``` e que para fazer o código funcionar preciso colocar um campo no formulário pedindo a inserção desse valor (usando requisição de dados pra agilizar), vc poderia reformular sua resposta em código PHP pois a ideia é que eu apenas use o ```$cd_itens_venda = $_POST['cd_itens_venda']```

Comment: Tenta assim:  `$cd_itens_venda = intval($_POST['cd_itens_venda']); `, o bindValue só aceita valores, vc pode tentar usar `bindParam()`

Comment: @IvanFerrer reformulei a pergunta, executa sem aparecer o erro no navegador, só que não faz a devolução da quantidade na tabela ```produto``` quando o registro na tabela ```itens_venda``` é excluído.

Answer (score 0):

vc pode definir o `$cd_produto` atráves de um `Select`, assim como fez com a quantidade, já que não o está recebendo via `$_POST`:

`$cd_produto = "SELECT cd_produto FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";`

Comment: Eu alterei a questão com base em sua resposta, executa sem aparecer o erro no navegador, só que não faz a devolução da quantidade na tabela ```produto``` quando o registro na tabela ```itens_venda``` é excluído.

Comment: envolva com parenteses as variáveis na query principal:

```$atualiza_quantidade = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade + ('$quantidade_vendida') WHERE cd_produto = ('$seleciona_produto')";```

Answer (score 0):

Há **n** erros no seu caso, vc está criando uma query falsa, porque vc não está pegando o valor retornado de uma query, mas a string dela:

Isso:

> 

```
$quantidade_vendida = "SELECT quantidade FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            // Query que faz a atualização da quantidade de estoque da tabela produto
            $atualiza_quantidade = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade + '$quantidade_vendida' WHERE cd_produto = '$seleciona_produto'";
```

> 

Irá retornará uma query SQL inválida:

```
UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade + 'SELECT quantidade FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda' WHERE cd_produto = '123';
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: O que não ficou claro pra vc?! Que vc não está concatenando dado, (sua primeira query não retorna nada, olha para o que vc escreveu), sua query é só uma concatenação de strings e nada mais, por isso está dando erro.

Comment: A variável `$seleciona_produto` não possui dados, ela é apenas a string da sua query.